# Next.js: backend server path is defined in next.config.js rewrites() but it returns 404 error

Tags: axios, next.js, server-rendering

This is the path I want to visit to:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/auth/profile/';
    const resp = await axios.get(url, {withCredentials: true})
    const json = await resp.json()
    console.log(json)
    return {
        props: {}
    }
};
```

This is next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
          {
            source: '/api/auth/:path*',
            destination: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/:path*'
          },
        ]
    },
}
```

But it's returning this:

```
Server Error

Error [ERR_FR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS]: Maximum number of redirects exceeded
```

What should I do?

Comment: In this scenario, is your Next.js app running on port `8000` and your backend server in port `3000`?

Comment: No no, backend is on port 8000 and nextjs port is 3000.

Comment: In what situation do you get the `ERR_FR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error? What page are you trying to access when that occurs?

Comment: My server address is `http://loclahost:8000/api/auth/login`, but in after declaring the above statements in `async rewrites(){...}` I decided to change the backend server address to `http://loclahost:3000/api/auth/login`. Then I got the `ERR_FR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

Comment: Right, but at what point do you get the error?

Comment: Just when the page at `localhost:3000/profile/` loads.

Comment: I think the reason is because the cookies are not saved in browser. I have added the question with description here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66679823/next-js-is-not-saving-any-cookie-returned-from-django-backend-in-browser-cookie.